# cordova/phonegap cant load js file in android

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, phonegap

**cordova/phonegap cant load js file in android**

I'm developing an cordova app for Android which has a lot of logic (js) and design (html/css) same as my web application. when we build iOS and browser it works fine, but when we build android, it cant load the js file in html...

```
<html>
    <script src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery_3_1_1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-2.0.2.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="app/users.js"></script>
</head>
<body class="app" onload="loadready();" >
<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
            alert(typeof loadready);
   });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

and users.js

```
function loadready() {
   alert("load");
}
```

in alert its always comes undefined

Comment: So your code is...? Or you will let us imagine it? xD https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Are you including all JS file in your index.html ??

Comment: Did you fix this issue?